# Using dnsmasq to resolve all hosts to the same address

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I'm running Ubuntu server on a computer used as a wireless AP, but this AP should resolve all DNS requests to an internal IP address rather than actually performing the lookup.

I want to do the same thing that paid public WiFi hotspots do - you can connect but if you attempt to load any websites they show a default page. I've noticed that they do this by resolving all domains to an internal IP address.

I've added these lines to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
# Add domains which you want to force to an IP address here.
# The example below send any host in double-click.net to a local
# web-server.
address=/com/192.168.2.1
address=/uk/192.168.2.1
address=/org/192.168.2.1
address=/gov/192.168.2.1
address=/net/192.168.2.1
address=/us/192.168.2.1
```

which works fine for those TLD's, but I'd like to be able to do it with all domains so I can sleep at night.

Comment: why not just use a captive portal like sputnik or the like? How do you plan to change DNS after they login?

Comment: [Trying to achieve this?](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html) If you edit your dhcpd and then do iptables -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.1

Comment: @PaulAckerman I used public WiFi as an example. This AP will *never* allow real DNS requests to be made.  

I'll try the iptables thing.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

### As the `dnsmasq` manual says …

… just use `#` for a wildcard:

```
address=/#/192.168.2.1
```

Comment: rtfm indeed but god bless you anyway :D

Comment: Which manual? 'man dnsmasq' gives me a BOAT LOAD of command line options, but almost no information on config file layout.

Comment: I know this is late, but in case someone finds this useful: all the long options in the dnsmasq man page are valid in config files as well - all you need to do is drop the preceding dashes (and put each option on its own line). Event the argument syntax remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Beware that although dnsmasq's manual might say anything in its version **2.86**

```
address=/#/…IP.IP.IP.IP…
```

no longer works — a bug probably.

Comment: Version 2.87 said replace address=/#/... function, but still not detailed. https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/CHANGELOG